# How to emphasise different parts of a phrase using "ne ... que"?

Tags: grammaire, traduction

I'm trying to work out how you would emphasise different parts of a phrase with "*ne ... que*".

If I want to say "*she only went there after a week*", suggesting that "a week" was a long time to take to go there, I would tentatively say

> *Elle n'y est allée qu'une semaine après son arrivée en France*

However, I don't know how to formulate the sentence if I want to emphasise the fact that it *only* took her a week to go to a place after she arrived in France, and that this was a short amount of time to take. In English, I would say "*she went there after only a week*".

How could I formulate that phrase with a clear emphasis but still using "*ne ... que*"? I have a suspicion that the French phrase I've given above might mean both depending on the context, but I'm really not sure.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you do have the right suspicion :

> Elle n'y est allée qu'une semaine après son arrivée en France.

can have both meanings :

> She only went there after a week.
>
> She went there after only a week.

It's because ne...que pattern is, **in this case**, only mark of remarkable duration.
The meaning will depend on the context, like in these two examples:

- Remarkably long time :

  > Il n'est venu me voir que 2 ans après son arrivée au village
- Remarkably short time :

  > Il n'a passé son permis qu'un jour après son frère.

So, to ensure that your sentence is well understood when context is not obvious, I think you will have to add something to your sentence to make it unambiguous.

Here are examples to translate "*she went there after only a week*" without ambiguity :

- Adding *seulement*:

  > Elle n'y est allée qu'une semaine **seulement** après son arrivée en France.
- Changing turn of phrase to add context:

  > **Il ne lui a fallu** qu'une semaine pour y aller après son arrivée en France.
  >
  > **Elle n'a attendu** qu'une semaine pour y aller après son arrivée en France.
  >
  > **Ça ne lui a pris** qu'une semaine pour y aller après son arrivée en France

Comment: Nice, but the last example sounds very odd to me...

Comment: Maybe "dès la première semaine après son arrivée en France" sounds less odd. I think the example is correct ("dès" is followed by a timestamp) but I agree that it sounds odd after repeating it more than 10 times.

Comment: Indeed, "dès" is much more natural followed by "la première semaine", but what follows wouldn't fit... I don't see a way to turn it right with the same meaning... it should be something like "dès la première semaine de cours" for instance...

Comment: I'm removing this example as it is not necessary at all for the point.

Comment: Really nice answer, just a thing: *Elle n'y est allée qu'une semaine seulement après son arrivée en France* sounds a bit redundant to me because of *ne... que* + *seulement*, but if you ommit *ne... que* so it's ambiguous again because *seulement* is ambiguous...

Answer (score 2):

Tac's answer is right about the ambiguity, so you could say:

> Elle n'y est allée qu'une **petite** semaine après son arrivée en France

Precising the week is *little*, you mean it was a short period. You could say *courte* (*short*) too.

Care about another ambiguity: the original phrase (and my proposition) could mean *She only went there for a week, when she arrived in France*.

Answer (score 1):

In my mind, the way to fix this is related to the fact that with a phrase like *ne ... que*, you're trying to "negate" a quantity or degree. The way that you currently have the sentence set up, you're matching *ne ... que* to the verb rather than to a quantity or degree. So, we can add that emphasis by trying to put a quantity or degree in there that we can then "negate" with *ne ... que*

I would say something like:

> Ce n'était qu'une semaine après son arrivée en France qu'elle y est allée ...

That way, it's the phrase "C'était une semaine après son arrivée" that we can "negate" rather than "Elle y est allée," which doesn't have a quantity or degree associated with it.

Comment: I think that your answer doesn't resolve the ambiguity, because you could also say "Ce n'était que 10 ans après son arrivée en France qu'elle y est allée" to mean it took her long time.

Comment: Could you? I've always been under the impression that *ne ... que* is a limiter, which implies that the quantity could be much bigger, but isn't. So, "Ce n'était que 10 ans après ..." would suggest to me that we expected her to stay for much longer than that (rather than emphasize that it took a long time).

Comment: On the other hand, if we did want to emphasize that length, I could see using a sentence like "Ce n'était qu'après 10 ans en France qu'elle y est allée"

Comment: +1 for noting that it’s not clear (at least to me) what is being limited in the OPs construction (in fact I see ambiguity in the English "she only went there after a week," ‘cause it could mean she went to/tried lots of places (bars?) during the first week, but after that she settled on one, her favorite). Regardless, +1 to @Tac , too, for the last 3 rewrites. In fact, your most recent comment suggesting “qu'après 10 ans en France” is my favorite and I think that construction might also work with the OPs original construction/word order:“Elle n'y est allée qu'après 10 ans/1 semaine en France.”

Answer (score -2):

> Ce n'est pas avant une semaine après son arrivée en France qu'elle y est allée.

Comment: Bienvenue sur FLSE ! Pouvez vous détailler votre réponse ? Ne donner qu'une solution sans explication n'aide pas beaucoup l'OP à comprendre les nuances. De plus, la phrase proposée sonne fausse a mon avis...

Comment: Sorry for not giving any explanation. Please consider my answer as an intuitive one as it's difficult for a non linguist native french speaker to understand the logic of its own language. Well, the sentence sounds strange. Sure, it's not beautiful, but it does the job. "pas avant" kills the ambiguity.

>Ce n'est pas avant un mois après son arrivée à Paris qu'elle a visité la Tour Eiffel !

Comment: Your answer does not add anything to the previous answers and I doubt any French native would say anything like that. I wouldn't.

Comment: For whatever reason, the OP states a desire to "still [use] *ne ... que*" and although your suggestion has "ne" near its beginning and "que" near its end, I, granted a non-native speaker, see it instead as using  the negating "ne ... pas" construction together with a stand-alone "que" serving as a conjunction to introduce a (circumstantial?/subordinate?) proposition. Regardless, +1 for technically, if not idiomatically, satisfying the OPs "ne ... que" requirement.