# Je ne comprends pas « tu as que »

Tags: expressions, négation

Je suis en train de regarder Marseille sur Netflix. Est-ce que l'on peut m'expliquer cette phrase de saison 1, épisode 3, 21:53.

> T'as qu'à le garder vu que tu l'as déchiré.

Contexte: un homme parle à une femme, ils se draguent. Il lui donne un poème et elle le déchire par accident.

Je ne comprends pas pourquoi "que" se place après "t'as" - ça veut dire "you have only to keep it, seeing as you ripped it" mais cette traduction n'a pas beaucoup du sens en anglais... Il y a peut-être une meilleure traduction.

Comment: C'est un dialogue familier, correctement énoncé : « T**u n** ' as qu'à … »

Comment: @Personne Il est un peu exagéré de dire qu'il n'est pas correctement énoncé vu que c'est de loin la prononciation majoritaire pour un dialogue en français courant.

Comment: @jlliagre … ce n'est pas par rapport au nombre de locuteurs, mais à la grammaire de base écornée, source de la question.

Comment: @Personne Oui, mais la grammaire normative du français écrit. Je pense qu'il vaut mieux éviter de dire à un apprenant qu'une tournure est incorrectement énoncée alors qu'elle correspond à la forme la plus courante utilisée à l'oral.

Answer (score 3):

Pour parler un peu de la grammaire, c'est un exemple de la construction **ne...que** mais à l'oral comme @Personne a dit dans un commentaire.  Comme le *ne* a tendance à disparaître quand on parle, on peut dire :

> T'as qu'à le garder vu que tu l'as déchiré.

pour exprimer

> Tu **n'as qu**'à le garder vu que tu l'as déchiré.

Ne...que veut dire "only" or "just".  C'est la négation et la restriction.

> Lorsque l’adverbe ne est suivi de la conjonction que, il indique une restriction et signifie « seulement ». ([BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?Th=2&t1=&id=2466))

On peut traduire la phrase en "Since you tore it, all you have to do is keep it." ou "Just keep it (you only have to keep it) since you ripped it."  En effet, c'est "All you have to do now is keep it seeing as how you ripped it."

---

To touch on the grammar, this is a spoken example of the construction **ne...que**. It is a negative restrictive construction where instead of pas, **que** means "only" or "just."

The *ne* is often glossed over in spoken French, so it's common to hear what you heard without the *ne*.  With it, and written, the sentence is:

> Tu **n'as qu**'à le garder vu que tu l'as déchiré.

Other possible translations: "You only have to keep it since you've ripped it." and "Seeing as how you tore it, just keep it."

[Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/french-english/ne-que) gives the following on ne...que:

> ne ... que
> (= seulement) only
>
> Il ne boit que de l’eau. He only drinks water.
>
> Je ne l’ai vu qu’une fois. I’ve only seen him once.

See also: [How to emphasise different parts of a phrase using “ne … que”?](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/21652/how-to-emphasise-different-parts-of-a-phrase-using-ne-que)

Answer (score 2):

Literally, he said:

> You just (have to=can) keep it given the fact you ripped it.

The meaning is more like:

> Just keep it, you ripped it anyway.